# codeigniter duplicate in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i am having a issue with codeigniter form validation.

my table is as

```
Sr#, name , dob,pic



$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Duplicate Name','trim|required|is_unique[mcb.name]');
```

now when i am trying to edit any record with sr# and check the form validation for name (as i dont want duplicate name too) it gives error.

what i am trying to do is update the record but i don't want duplicate name too.

now for example if i edit the record and don't change name but change

> DOB

but it shows the duplicate name.

i want to check duplicate name but not in row i am going to update.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is kind of easy I think (if I got your question right)

make two sets of rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Duplicate Name','trim|required|is_unique[mcb.name]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Duplicate Name','trim|required');
```

make a `if()` before using `validation->run()`

like this

```
if ( strtoupper($this->input->post('name')) == strtoupper($old_name) ) { //pass old name in hidden field or load it before this condition via model

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Duplicate Name','trim|strtoupper|required');

} else {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Duplicate','trim|required|strtoupper|is_unique[mcb.name]');

}

//all other form_validation checks here

if ($this->form_validation->run()) {}
```

//edit
added `strtoupper()` so your unique values are really unique